# How to add a speaker to webots project (in C)?

Tags: webots

I want to use  `wb_speaker_speak(WbDeviceTag tag, const char *text, double volume)` in my webots project (in C). Here is my try (for simplicity I've avoid main and other related functions):

```
 1 #include <webots/speaker.h>
    
 2 static WbDeviceTag Speaker;
 3 Speaker = wb_robot_get_device("Speaker");
 4 wb_speaker_speak(Speaker, "Hi", 1);
```

But I get the error:

```
Warning: "Speaker" device not found.
Error: wb_speaker_speak(): invalid device tag.
```

I think the problem is in the line 3! How can I see the list of available devices to be able to define the speaker correctly?
And is it necessary to add a real speaker device to the environment? If so, then how? Because I didn't see an speaker object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct.
And the error is exactly that the name argument you are passing to the `wb_robot_get_device()` function doesn't exists.

By default the [Speaker](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/speaker) device name is "speaker" in lower case.

Unfortunately there is no quick way to see all the devices names at once from the UI but you should check in the node definition.
You can do it in from the Webots Scene Tree or, if your robot is a PROTO, you should open the PROTO file and search for the [Speaker](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/speaker) device.
If the `name` field is not specified in the [Speaker](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/speaker) node, then it is using the default value "speaker".

To make it work it is sufficient to add the [Speaker](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/speaker) device as a child of your robot node but the world and you don't have to add any real speaker.
You can run a sample simulation using the [Speaker](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/speaker) device by opening the sample named "speaker.wbt" in from the Webots menu "File > Open Sample World.." and selecting the section "samples > devices."

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://www.cyberbotics.com/).*

Comment: Thanks @stefania-pedrazzi for the clear response. Yes, I had to add the speaker device as a child to my robot. The only challenge was that, I was using a remote PROTO file. So I had to save it locally (right click on the robot -> Edit PROTO), next, add the speaker to its children node (copied the speaker device from one of the Sample World, e.g., speaker_text_to_speech.wbt), and then add the robot in the world file like this: `DEF ROBOT robot {
  controller "robot_demo"
}` , then it worked like a charm.